# Set scala eclipse language to english_uk

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scalding

I have a text file that i am reading through scalding Textline function. Problem is that my file has multiple £ sign in it. but as the default language is en_US, eclipse by default converts that £ into a �. I'm sure that i have to change the language somewhere to en_UK. but i dont know where to do that.

I have tried adding this in windows-> preference -> Java -> installed java and adding this

> -Duser.language=en_UK -Duser.country=UK

to Default VM arguments, but the output remains same ..

PS- using eclipse keepler. 
any recommendations are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm getting you right, but I guess that you could solve you problem either way.

1. Eclipse just can't display the correct sign, then you should tell eclipse to use Unicode character (explained here: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/02/21/pro-tip-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console/)
2. If you read in you file programmatically you have to use the correct charset, again utf-8. But this is hard to answer because you don't provide any code.